# On Mac command-line, how to execute a SQL statement in file foo.sql and export result in tab separated form into another file?

Tags: mysql, sql, file

On Mac command-line,

```
$ sql -u foo -pbar db -B -e "SELECT * FROM t" > output.txt
```

requires entering the command inline.

How to execute a SQL statement in file foo.sql and still export result in tab separated form into another file?

### EDIT

When I do

```
mysql -h localhost -u foo -pbar db -B -e "SELECT * FROM t WHERE x='{}' LIMIT 2 INTO OUTFILE '../o.tsv';"
```

I got error

```
ERROR 1045 (28000) at line 1: Access denied for user 'foo'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

But strangely,

```
mysql -h localhost -u foo -pbar db
```

gives me mysql command prompt fine. Does using `OUTFILE` require user `foo` having a special previlege?

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM user WHERE User='foo'\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                 Host: localhost
                 User: foo
             Password: *A5DB2D927D6DF94DA5E1CE4B2AEAAB4D8304EA
          Select_priv: N
          Insert_priv: N
          Update_priv: N
          Delete_priv: N
          Create_priv: N
            Drop_priv: N
          Reload_priv: N
        Shutdown_priv: N
         Process_priv: N
            File_priv: N
           Grant_priv: N
      References_priv: N
           Index_priv: N
           Alter_priv: N
         Show_db_priv: N
           Super_priv: N
Create_tmp_table_priv: N
     Lock_tables_priv: N
         Execute_priv: N
      Repl_slave_priv: N
     Repl_client_priv: N
     Create_view_priv: N
       Show_view_priv: N
  Create_routine_priv: N
   Alter_routine_priv: N
     Create_user_priv: N
             ssl_type: 
           ssl_cipher: 
          x509_issuer: 
         x509_subject: 
        max_questions: 0
          max_updates: 0
      max_connections: 0
 max_user_connections: 0
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After setting `File_priv` to true, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Does:

```
sql -u foo -pbar db -B -e `cat foo.sql` > output.txt
```

work?

Comment: There is ERROR 1045 (28000) . See in OP.

Answer (score -1):

Use `SELECT [text of query] INTO OUTFILE [filename]`. Here's [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select-into.html). If the format isn't exactly what you want, see the [load data infile](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html) syntax for formatting commands you can specify after the filename.

Comment: How to execute a SQL statement stored in a file from command-line?

Comment: `mysql < foo.sql` should work. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/batch-commands.html for more info.

Comment: That probably means you need to specify a username and password (and probably database) when you run `mysql`. The full command would look like `mysql -u yourusername -p databasename < foo.sql`. After you enter the command it should ask for your password.